# Javascript, adding to a variable not setting

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble adding to a var at the moment I can only get it to set, I tried a number of operators like "+=" "++" but it doesn't work :(

I have a function that gets called a number of times inside I have this

```
score = Math.floor((Math.random()*15)*1);
```

But when it gets activated the function runs and sets the score then when its run again it overwrites the old score with the new random number, I want to add the old score plus whatever is generated together do I need a 2nd var?

When I tried to use `score += Math.floor((Math.random()*15)*1);` I got the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: score is not defined

Comment: If `score += Math.floor((Math.random()*15)*1);` doesn't work, then we need more code.

Comment: What happened when you did `+=`?

Comment: Hmm I tried that when I then score I get 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: score is not defined"
I think maybe then its something to do with my js library

Comment: Sounds like a scope problem then. Is `score` defined as a local variable in a scope narrower than the one you call `Math.random()` in?

Comment: There is definitely something else going on. We'll need you to provide us a larger portion of the code to be able to determine what the problem is.

Comment: You have to show more code if you want get a good diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me take a guess, score was not declared to be an Int but a string

try

```
var score = 0;
score += Math.floor((Math.random()*15)*1);
```

Comment: I did have it set to "var score;" now its "var score = 0" and I get 
 "Uncaught ReferenceError: score is not defined"

Comment: @user2598957 are you defining score some where else?? like global context? if so do this.score += Math.floor((Math.random()*15)*1);

Comment: Got it, I just twigged as I saw this post thanks for your help! score was in a create (load) function

Comment: *"are you defining score some where else?? like global context? if so do this.score"* If `score` is a global variable, then just using `score` should work. If you want to explicit about it, use `window.score`, *not* `this.score`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `score += Math.floor((Math.random()*15)*1);` really means `score = score + Math.floor((Math.random()*15)*1);`, but, since you haven't defined `score` anywhere yet, when it tries to use it in the calculation, it is "undefined" (and tells you as much   :D   ).

Define `score` before attempting to use the `+=` operator on it and you should be fine.